# packstack openstack ussuri cannot use cli

Tags: openstack, openstack-keystone

I installed packstack openstack ussri on my virtual box without any issue (CLI and dashboard).

When I tried to install it on my company's environment, I can't use CLI commands. There was no error in the installation. I can login to the dashboard and do stuffs there, though.

The error thrown:

```
Failed to discover available identity versions when contacting http://ipaddr:5000/v3. Attempting to parse version from URL.
Proxy Authentication Required (HTTP 407)
```

This is what the generated keystonerc_admin file looks like after installation, very similar to what i have in virtual box:

```
unset OS_SERVICE_TOKEN
    export OS_USERNAME=admin
    export OS_PASSWORD='***'
    export OS_REGION_NAME=RegionOne
    export OS_AUTH_URL=http://ipaddr:5000/v3
    export PS1='[\u@\h \W(keystone_admin)]\$ '

export OS_PROJECT_NAME=admin 
export OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME=Default 
export OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME=Default 
export OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=3
```

I tried the solution (install python3.8 and install openstackclient via pip) in the other similar thread to no avail. I still get the same error.

I wonder why my setup in virtual box works while the one deployed in the company's network don't?

Any ideas what I need to check/modify to resolve this issue? fairly new to openstack...

Let me know what files i need to provide in order to help.

Thanks in advance!

~rad

Comment: I think the error message is pretty clear, your proxy settings require some modifications. I assume that you should add your control node (`ìpaddr`) to the no_proxy list so your machine doesn't try connect via your company's proxy.